# Append text using jquery and onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get "$(newList).click(function)..." below to work.

This is part of a "list" creator, at first when user click on a "createlist" button an input is created with a save button. This input is the `newList` variable in the code below.
The save button should happen the text entered in the input as an h1 title on the page.

Right now when you enter something in the input field and hit "save", nothing happens.

Please see entire snippet here: http://jsfiddle.net/aortic/4Uhrt/1/ . Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var newList = '<p class="nameList">NAME THE LIST</p><input type="text" name="list"    id="listName"><a href="#newModule" class="save">SAVE</a>';
  var dragItems = '<p class="dragItems">DRAG ITEMS IN HERE</p>';

  $("#createList").click(function(){
    $(this).remove();
    $("#newModule").append(newList);
  }); 

  $(newList).click(function(){
    $(this).remove();
    $("#newModule").append("<h1>" +$("#listName").val()+"</h1>");
    $("#listName").val("");
  });
});
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4Uhrt/4/)..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var newList = '<div class="add"><p class="nameList">NAME THE LIST</p><input type="text" name="list" id="listName" class="listName"><a href="#newModule" class="save">SAVE</a></div>';
    var dragItems = '<p class="dragItems">DRAG ITEMS IN HERE</p>';

    $("#createList").click(function(){
      $(this).hide();
      $("#newModule").append(newList);
    }); 

    $(document).on('click', '.save', function(){
        $("#newModule").append("<h1>" +$("#listName").val()+"</h1");

        $('.add').remove();
        $('#createList').show();
    });
});
```

I'll have to run a little bit more tests, but worked...

Answer (score 0):

You can't put items in jQuery like this

> $(newList).click(function()

You need to put id or class in css for getting items instance.Right now you are putting html in newList variable.

Answer (score -1):

I'd use event delegation like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var newList = '<div><p class="nameList">NAME THE LIST</p><input type="text" name="list" id="listName"><a href="#newModule" class="save">SAVE</a></div>';
    var dragItems = '<p class="dragItems">DRAG ITEMS IN HERE</p>';
    $("#createList").click(function () {
        $(this).remove();
        $("#newModule").append(newList);
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.save', function () {
        $("#newModule").append("<h1>" + $("#listName").val() + "</h1>");$(this).closest('div').remove();
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4Uhrt/3/)**